# How to make seed method, with the current user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I make a seed method, that create a user?

How to I make another seed methoad that uses the `ApplicationUserId` in the new method? Have tried

```
var id = User.Identity.GetUserById();
```

When I update the database it comes with an error, that theres is an conflict in the `AspNetUsers` table with the foreign key to my table

Comment: Updating the database (when seeding happens) occurs outside of the lifecycle of a web request. Heck, it's not even required that IIS be running. You can't get the "current" user when seeding, because no such thing exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use your dbContext to find the ID of the user created previously. So, after create your user, call the SaveChanges method and after this do:

```
var id = context.Users.Where(x => x.UserName == "youruser").FirstOrDefault().Id;
```